# Command to empty many files recursively

Tags: bash, macos, command

I would like to clear the content of many log files of a given directory recursively, without deleting every file. Is that possible with a simple command?

I know that I can do `> logs/logfile.log` one by one, but there are lots of logs in that folder, and that is not straightforward.

I am using macOS Sierra by the way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to @chepner for showing me the better way to protect against double quotes in the file names:

You can use `find` to do it

```
find start_dir -type f -exec sh -c '> "$1"' _ {} \;
```

And you could add extra restrictions if you don't want all files, like if you want only files ending in `.log` you could do

```
find start_dir -type f -name '*.log' -exec sh -c '> "$1"' _ {} \;
```

Answer (score 1):

As macOS includes **Perl** anyway:

```
perl -e 'for(<logs/*log>){truncate $_,0}'
```

Or, more succinctly, if you use **homebrew** and you have installed **GNU Parallel** (which is just a Perl script), you can do:

```
parallel '>' ::: logs/*log
```